# Changing Formula Source Value when different | Excel

Tags: excel

Essentially I have a 2 columns in excel one with names that are listed once that change every few rows and another column that called "List Names" that repeat on every line but change based on what is in the first column.

**For example:**

This is an example of the end result.

[image]

How can a formula be written for the `List Names` column to change the name based on the last name based on what it was last in the first column?

Please Note if the name changes in the first column, the second column will use the new name on the next row (See Above)

**Example of Incorrect Results:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A1<>"",A1,B1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

Comment: When the name changes in column A it updates Column B for one row and then switch back to the previous name

Comment: @Charlin  Be sure you are putting the formula in **B2** and not **B1** ......................data must match your picture................see my picture.

Comment: Yes my data does match yours but I am getting a circular reference error when dragging.

Comment: @Charlin  I don't see how...the **B2** formula only references **A1** and **B1**.  These are the cells above it.

Comment: Please see my updates post, I posted an example of the issue

Comment: The formula seems to revert back to the name previously mentioned in column A

Comment: @Charlin  **I think I see the problem!**  From both your first and second pictures, I assumed that *John* is in **A1** and the words *List Names* are in **B1** ....................That is why I told you to put my formula in **B2**.

Comment: Got it, yes that was my mistake. Thank you for your help

Comment: We both knew it had to be something simple..................your second picture gave me the hint I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I've just made following Excel sheet:

```
One   <empty>
      <empty>
      <empty>
      <empty>
Two   <empty>
      <empty>
      <empty>
Three <empty>
      <empty>
      <empty>
```

In order to fill the second column, I first set the formula `=A1` in cell "B1".
In the other cells, I've put the following formula:

```
=If(ISBlank(A2);B1;A2)
```

Then I dragged this formula to cell "B10".

I realise this is not exactly the result you're hoping for, but I've seen in your example having "John" next to "Mary" and "Mary" next to "Mark", and I think there's a mistake in your example.